# getting NSView from wxpython GetHandle function on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, wxpython, vlc

I am using wxpython 3.0.2 and trying to have vlc play the video on a panel. But from what I read, the `GetHandle()` returns a reference to the wxpython widget and not the underlying `NSView`.

This post ([NSView* from wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014804/nsview-from-wxpython)) talks about a function to convert the return value as an `NSView`, but I am not sure where to implement this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is due to not using the native python (`/usr/bin/python`).